# Hibernate annotations @Table @UniqueConstraint inheritance

Tags: hibernate, unique-constraint, hibernate-annotations

I have a Java model for Hibernate where the mapping is done via annotations.
I have an abstract `@MappedSuperClass` which contains properties that need to be unique so I used the `@Table` annotation with some `@UniqueConstraint`.

My problem is that the constraints are not inherited by the children.
It works well if I copy/paste the unique constraints in every child class but it seems to me that a cleaner solution should exist :)

Here is the relevant code:

```
@MappedSuperClass
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"firstname", "lastname"}))
public abstract class Person {
  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;

  // Constructors/Getters/Setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee extends Person {
  // Some specific properties, constructors, getters/setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "partner")
public class Partner extends Person {
  // Some specific properties, constructors, getters/setters
}


public void testCase() {
  Employee employee1 = new Employee("John", "Doe");
  Employee employee2 = new Employee("John", "Doe");

  this.employeeDAO.save(employee1);
  this.employeeDAO.save(employee2); // I'd like an exception here!
}
```

Is there a way to get that constraint working without duplicating it in every child class?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you try removing the @Table and placing a @Column(unique=true) on the property in the MappedSuperClass instead?

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. The problem is that I don't want the properties to be unique individually but I need a unique constraint on the couple formed by the 2 properties.

Comment: I have the same problem. Although I have no @Table annotations on my child entities, Table annotation from the super class is still not inherited. Did you find solution for this?
By the way I can't even copy constraint to child entity, because Hibernate throws exception saying "database column 'columnname' not found." (coulmnname is defined in parent entity)

Comment: I didn't find any solution and ended up copy/pasting the constraints... :(